# Java - Return field value of class that extends the super class

Tags: java

When I create an instance of "Sword", and calls the getName(), I receive null.  How can I make it so that getName() in Weapon class returns whatever "name" is set to in Weapon.

```
public abstract class Weapon extends items.Item {

    public String name;

    public int damage;

    public ItemType itemType = ItemType.Weapon;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

}

public class Sword extends Weapon{

    int damage = 10;
    int manaCost = 0;
    String name = "Steel Sword";
}
```

Comment: Sword's name variable is hiding name in Weapon, Just say `name = "Steel Sword";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `name` variable in `Sword` is different than the one in `Weapon` -- it *hides* the one in `Sword`.  When you have a variable of type `Weapon`, accessing name will access `Weapon`'s `name`, which is uninitialized, so it remains `null`.

Instead of declaring a new variable, you can create a constructor in `Sword` that sets the existing `name` variable to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constructor to your `Weapon` class so that all of its subclasses must use it to initialize the correct data for that class

```
public abstract class Weapon {

    public String name;
    public int damage;
    public ItemType itemType = ItemType.Weapon;

    public Weapon(String name, int damage) {//Constructor for creating a weapon to be used by subclasses
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
    }
}
```

And then to create a `Sword` with the name "Sword" and damage of 10 you would just invoke its superclasses constructor like this:

```
public class Sword extends Weapon {

    public Sword() {
        super("Sword", 10); //Calls the constructor from the Weapon class with the values "Sword" and 10
    }
}
```

I would think this is the much preferred solution, because it will cause compile time warnings if `Sword` does not call the constructor for a weapon, and it will ensure that all the fields are initialized correctly.